# Simplest algorithm for edge coloring of a dodecahedron?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, coloring, polyhedra, origami

I have an origami model of a dodecahedron I am assembling. There are 30 edges with 3 colors of 10 each. I could use a diagram that gives a possible 3 color edge coloring. However, is there some sort of simple algorithm I can follow which will easily give me a 3 color edge coloring?

Comment: Why don't you search for a picture and copy its pattern? If you definetely need a method, you could devise a hamiltonain cycle (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IcosianGame.html)) and then color it with two colors, and all the rest with the third color.

Answer (score 3):

Each face of the dodecahedron $D$ has four vertices where the counterclockwise order of the edge colors is, e.g., $1\to2\to3\to$, and one vertex where it is $1\to3\to2\to$. There are $4$ vertices of the second kind on $D$, forming a regular tetrahedron. (This has to do with the possible four-colorings of the faces of $D$.)